# How to add the Image.RenderTransform tag to an image within a scrollViewer in Silverlight

Tags: xml, silverlight-4.0

This may end up being a really dumb question so please forgive me if this is simple - I am fairly new to silverlight :)

What I would like to do is add the Image.RenderTransform example below to my own project but my image control is within a scrollviewer and whenever I try to add it I get the message :

"The attachable property "RenderTransform" was not found in type "Image"

```
<Image MaxHeight="220" MaxWidth="200" Name="image1" Stretch="Uniform" Source="/FunWithMouseWheel;component/Images/sl4bloglogo.png" MouseWheel="image1_MouseWheel" Margin="531,346,124,199">
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <ScaleTransform x:Name="imageScale"></ScaleTransform>
    </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

---

My Xaml file:

```
<UserControl x:Class=Image_Viewer.MainPage"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
          Background="White" Height="717" Width="1086">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="713*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="456*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Content="Button" Height="35" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="btnGet" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="115" Click="btnGet_Click" />
        <Button Content="Rotate Left" Height="35" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="132,10,0,0" Name="btnRotateLeft" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="115" />

        <ScrollViewer Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="520" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="37,60,0,0" Name="scrollViewer" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="840" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ScrollViewer.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5" StartPoint="0,0.5">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF89D2FC" Offset="0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#00009AFF" Offset="1" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </ScrollViewer.Background>
            <Image Height="465" Name="imgData" Stretch="Uniform" Width="767" MouseLeftButtonDown="imgData_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseWheel="imgData_MouseWheel" />

        <Image.RenderTransform></Image.RenderTransform> <----- causes the error
        </ScrollViewer>
        <Slider Height="248" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="222,60,0,0" Name="slider" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="39" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="1" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it - it was simple in the end!

The problem was that the Image tag was closed in the line:

```
 <Image Height="465" Name="imgData" Stretch="Uniform" Width="767" MouseLeftButtonDown="imgData_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseWheel="imgData_MouseWheel" />
```

So I simply removed the closing tag / and inserted the Image.RenderTransform tag and an additional  closing tag:

```
    <Image Height="465" Name="imgData" Stretch="Uniform" Width="767" MouseLeftButtonDown="imgData_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseWheel="imgData_MouseWheel">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
```